# Why public Maven dependency exist, but cannot download, and how to fix? This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not re

Tags: java, maven

File `pom.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Foo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>PCDRetention</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-dom</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-ext-jdk16</artifactId>
            <version>1.45</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.sisu.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- asm-all:3.3.1 cannot migrate. -->
        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>-->
        <!--    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>-->
        <!--    <version>1.6.6</version>-->
        <!--    <scope>runtime</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>-->
        <!--    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>-->
        <!--    <version>1.6.6</version>-->
        <!--    <scope>runtime</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Almost dependencies can download, but few dependency cannot download.

```java
commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:pom:1.4 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:pom:1.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4/commons-dbcp-1.4.pom

Try to run Maven import with -U flag (force update snapshots)
```

[image]

I don't prefer solution install Maven local from JAR file. How to fix?

Comment: rerun your build outside of Eclipse via command line as given: `mvn clean package -U`...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is just to remove the artifact from your local maven repository and rerun the import.  If you haven't modified your maven settings to point to a non-default repository path, you'll find the artifact in `~/.m2/repository/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4`.  Remove this directory and rerun the import.

Maven has a settings file that governs its behavior.  It is located in in `$M2_HOME/conf`, where `$M2_HOME` is the home directory of your maven installation.  This file is called `settings.xml`.

You can use the `<localRepository/>` directive to change where maven stores the artifacts it pulls down.  You can find the reference documentation for this and other settings [here](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html).

Essentially you just need to locate where your local artifacts are stored and remove that one.  The default is in your home directory under the folder, `.m2/repository`

Comment: Please more detail and explain about *If you haven't modified your maven settings to point to a non-default repository path*